# Is an unhandled exception acceptable?

Tags: user-interface

After experiencing numerous problems with a certain media player, it got me thinking is it really acceptable to prompt the user to launch a debugger or terminate an application without any relevant information in this day and age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently.  Did you uninstall the media player?

Seriously, I'd say "no, it's not acceptable."  But there seem to be a lot of vendors who disagree with me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not, but you know **shit happens** :) There is no big difference between "a shiny oh exception happened, please call us" and "just classical debug window message".

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot the media player "magically" seemed to work again, I just think "tell me what is wrong and I will try to fix it" instead of just exiting on me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

While you can't really predict all exceptions that may be raised on your program that you didn't account for, you can surely catch `System.Exception` at the top of your program and present a dialog box telling the user to report the info to you. (Maybe with even an automated system to do that online.)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, surely the "last line of defence", in this case as you say a System.Exception should give the user a hint of what is wrong so they can take action.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just laziness or incompetence on the part of the developer?

Answer (score 0):

No.

(Actually, that's my entire answer, but SO doesn't like answers that concise, so I had to add this random sentence! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your audience imho.

If you're targeting the "average Joe" users, I'd say catch your mother-exception on top-level. Terminate the application and tell the user that something has gone wrong (please don't use a "call us" or "report bug" sentence - They are useless).

If you're targeting developers (a lá in-house development) an unhandled exception is okay-ish IMHO, but the best thing would be to print and / or log the stack-trace and all other information you got available along with a link to a site where it say's who's responsible for the application and who to contact if the problem persists.

Comment: "aka. in-house development" shouldve been "a lá" :)